# Can you display real-time data in a text field from a class that is not a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to C # and I'm making an application for sending mail. What I want to do is to display in a Textbox field the emails that I send in real time.

Operation: When I run the application it communicates with the database and gets the records, then with a while I go through those records and send the corresponding mail. So far so good and it works.

What I want to do: after sending each mail what I want to do is to display in a textbox the email sent in real time, but I am unable to do so.

Below I show a very simple very simple code of the structure of my project.

```
/****************CLASS FORM1***************************/
namespace envioEmails
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /********Shipping button*********/
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Consultas objetoConsultas = new Consultas();
            objetoConsultas.consultaBaseDatos();

        }


        private void campoTextBox_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //In this textbox is where I want to display the data in real time.          
        }

    }
}   

/*********CLASS CONSULTAS (This class is not a form)*******************/


namespace envioEmails
{

    class Consultas
    {

        public void consultaBaseDatos(){

            //Here I connect to the database and get the records.

            //Then I run the records with a while ...
            while(myreader.Read()){
                string email=myreader["emails"].ToString());
                if(this.enviarCorreo(email){
                    /**This is where I should call the fieldTextBox event, but I am unable to do so.**/
                    campoTextBox.Text=email;
                }

            }
        }

        private bool enviarCorreo(string email){
             //I connect to the SMTP server and send the mail.

            try
            {
                //Code for sending ....
                return true;
            }
            catch()
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried to instantiate the Form1 class inside the While and point to the event as shown in the following code, but I did not get any results

```
while(myreader.Read())
{
  string email=myreader["emails"].ToString());
  if(this.enviarCorreo(email){

      Form1 formularioPadre = new Form1();
     ((TextBox)formularioPadre.Controls["campoTextBox"]).Text = email;

    }
}
```

Thank you for your future answers.

Comment: I don't understand what the `TextChanged` event has to do with this. Can  you explain?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably changing your `consultaBaseDatos` to return a `List<string>` with the emails:

```
public List<string> consultaBaseDatos(){
    List<string> listEmails= new List<string>();    
    //Here I connect to the database and get the records.

    //Then I run the records with a while ...
     while(myreader.Read())
     {
         string email=myreader["emails"].ToString());
         if(this.enviarCorreo(email)
         {
                /**This is where I should call the fieldTextBox event, but I am unable to do so.**/
                listEmails.Add(email);
         }
     }
     return listEmails;
}
```

Then, in your form you can do simply:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Consultas objetoConsultas = new Consultas();
    List<string> listEmails=objetoConsultas.consultaBaseDatos();
    campoTextBox.Text=string.Join(",",listEmails);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it does not work.
In your example, the content is displayed at the end of the program, but what I need to do is show it during execution.

Comment: Then i would go using a Event, raise that event with each email and subscribe to it in your form

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment for now so I'm gonna have to post this as an answer.

It seems to me that that you need a trigger to check for emails sent and update your textfield content on a regular basis. Have you tried using timer control? Every "timer tick event", you can check if there are email list to be diplayed, update your textfield if there is.

Comment: Do not worry. I have already solved. I had to create a thread to run in the background. But thank you so much for your help.